# Prove that any two continuous functions from a simply connected, locally path connected space to the circle are homotopic.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I came across a problem I just cannot seem to figure out:

> Let $X$ be a simply connected, locally path-connected space, and let $f,g:X \to \mathbb{S}^1 $ (that is how John Lee denotes the unit circle) be two continuous functions.
> Prove $f\simeq g $ (i.e. $f$ and $g$ are homotopic).

Is the trick to show that $f$ and $g$ are each homotopic to a constant map?
The most I could think of was that since $X$ is simply connected, the image of any loop based at $x\in X$ under $f$ and $g$ is null path-homotopic. However $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ may not be equal. Also, we are not given that $f$ or $g$ are surjective.

Or are we supposed to create a homotopy between $f$ and $g$?

Would anyone be willing to give a suggestion on how to think about this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Any two maps $f,g$ would lift to maps into $\mathbb{R}$ since $\mathbb{R}$ covers $S^1$ by the lifting property and the fact that $X$ is simply connected. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible, any continuous map from any topological space into $\mathbb{R}$ is null homotopic. This finishes the proof.

Comment: So if $\tilde{f} $ and $\tilde{g}$ are the respective lifts and $\varepsilon : \mathbb{R} \to S^1 $ is the covering map, we can say $f = \varepsilon \circ \tilde{f} \simeq \varepsilon \circ c_* = c_{\varepsilon(*)} $? Similar for $g$?

Comment: yes. You can also then push down the homotopy.